# Does the Sorcerer Draconic Resilience stack with Barbarian Unarmored Defense?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, stacking, barbarian, armor-class

If you had a dexterity of 30 and a wisdom or constitution of 30, with Unarmored Defense for  Barbarian your AC while not wearing armor would be 10+your dexterity modifier + your constitution modifier for a Barbarian. Your AC would be 30 because 10+10+10=30. If you had a dexterity of 30 and were a Sorcerer of the Draconic Bloodline, you would gain the  feature of Draconic Resilience, your AC when you are not wearing armor would be 13+ dexterity modifier. That means your AC would be 23 because 13+10=23. So if you were a Barbarian/Sorcerer multiclass, could your AC hypothetically stack to 33 because 13+10+10=33?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If multiple things/effects give you more than 1 way to calculate your AC you pick one, you can't combine them.

So in your example the character either has 10+DEX+WIS or 10+DEX+CON or 13+DEX, but never 13+DEX+CON/WIS.

Comment: Note that there are straight up AC boosts available, but they're not phrased as a new way to *calculate* AC. Shields stack, Warforged get a straight +1 AC that stacks with *any* AC calculation they might use, etc.